# Value cannot be null c#.net

Tags: c#

I am creating a simple project on c#.net. I want to put the AutoNo textbox in my program. I have put but it is not working. it shown the error while ran program error said that

> Value cannot be null Parameter name: Stringmscorlib

Code what I tried I attached below

```
   public void Load()
{
    SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=test1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=admin123");
    Con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select id from records", Con);
    Data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (Data.Read() != false)
    {



        auto = int.Parse(Data[0].ToString());


    }
    try
    {

        int newid = auto;
        int id = newid + 1;
        this.textBox1.Text = "S00" + id.ToString();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.Source);
    }

    Data.Close();
}
```

}

Comment: do you have ex.stacktrace result?

Comment: Value cannot be null Parameter name: Stringmscorlib this message displayed error sir

Comment: I mean which line causes exception?

Comment: on which line it throws error

Comment: which *line* throws this error? I'm guessing it is the `auto = Data.GetString(0)` - in which case, for one of the rows, the first column simply has a null database value. Fix that, or check for null.

Comment: The stack trace, if you were to show it in the message box, would probably show that the exception comes from `Int32.Parse`

Comment: use try catch all of the script in Load() first, use Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace) to find which line causes exception

Comment: Better still, use the debugger. Debugging by scattering print statements over your code is a bit 1990s

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems I can see here; the first would be: what if there are zero rows? what is `auto` then? is it `null`? then `int.Parse(null)` will fail. You don't actually show where `auto` is declared, which makes this bit a little hard to intuit about.

The other possibility is here:

```
auto = Data.GetString(0);
```

in which case: this is simply a null database value. Check for that, and handle it:

```
if (Data.IsDBNull(0))
{ ... do whatever; perhaps just "continue" }
else
{
    auto = Data.IsDBNull(0);
    // and process it, etc
}
```

But frankly, you're making life hard for yourself here; here's the same thing with a tool like Dapper:

```cs
using (var conn= new SqlConnection("...whatever..."))
{
    // here we're asserting *exactly* zero or one row
    string auto = conn.QuerySingleOrDefault<string>("select id from records");

    if (auto == null)
    { ... do something else? ... }
    else
    {
        var newid= int.Parse(auto);
    }
}
```

Note: your query could currently return any number of rows; since the code only processes the last value, I suggest that the SQL needs fixing; perhaps `MAX`, `MIN`, or `TOP 1` with an `ORDER BY` clause; i.e. something like `select MAX(id) as [id] from records`. Note, however, that this sounds like a scenario where you should *probably* have used `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in some query that added or inserted the value. And an `id` should **very rarely** be a `string`.

Comment: `Data.IsDNBull(0)` LOL ;) (Edited it, but had to share the laugh)

Answer (score 0):

Parse method is not able to handle null value. Assuming auto is variable name.

instead of this

```
 int newid = Int32.Parse(auto);
```

use something like below

```
int newid=0;
int.TryParse(auto, out newid);
```

Comment: can you check Console.WriteLine(auto) ?

Comment: sir i modified code above now it is working S001 will displayed when the form is load but after add the record it not incremented by 1 . like S002

Comment: instead of select id from table use select max(id) from table.

Comment: auto = int.Parse(Data[0].ToString()); in this point have a error of An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: check with Convert.ToString(Data[0]) after that use int.TryParse Method what i mentioned in a Answer

Comment: can you check what is Returning Data[0] using debug method

Comment: return 0 sir. at the debug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200798/discussion-between-negi-rox-and-jaya-priya).